# Are there any weighted keyboards with 61 or less keys?

Tags: recommendations, piano

I need a keyboard that I can play live that is smaller than a full piano, but has weighted keys. I currently have Korg Krome 61 key, but I really only use the piano sounds and wish I had weighted keys.

I would also prefer it had really great piano sounds on it and was under $1000.

Thanks!
Matthew

Comment: Some web searching seems to indicate "No". There are 76-key fully-weighted options, and 61-key semi-weighted options. I haven't found a 61-key or smaller fully-weighted keyboard of any kind online.

Comment: @toddwilcox thanks for looking. still searching myself!